# How to run python file from php

Tags: php, python-3.x

I need help to figure out how to run a python file from php script.
Can someone let me know the complete procedure how to run a python file from php.

Appreciating your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution

```
/*
<complete path of python> '/usr/local/bin/python3';
<python file> 'test.py';
*/

$file_path = '<complete path of python> <python file>';

$command = escapeshellcmd($file_path);
$output = shell_exec($command);

var_dump($output);
```

let me know, if you face any other issue.
Happy coding